# Custom SilverStripe Module gets installed into vendor folder

Tags: php, composer-php, silverstripe

I've created a module and its in my private repo. I've created a `composer.json` file for it:

```
{
    "name": "company/sync",
    "description": "sync",
    "type": "silverstripe-module",
    "authors": [{
        "name": "XXXX",
        "email": "XXXX"
    }],
    "require": {
        "silverstripe/framework": "~3.2",
        "composer/installers": "~1.0"
    },
    "extra": {
        "installer-name": "sync"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

And I've got my main projects `composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "silverstripe/installer",
    "description": "The SilverStripe Framework Installer",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "company/sync",
                "version": "master",
                "source": {
                    "url": "git@xxx:xxx/sync.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "silverstripe/cms": "3.3.1",
        "silverstripe/framework": "3.3.1",
        "silverstripe/reports": "3.3.1",
        "silverstripe/siteconfig": "3.3.1",
        "silverstripe-themes/simple": "3.1.*",
        "company/sync": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/PHPUnit": "~3.7"
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "3.x-dev": "3.3.x-dev"
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "sync": ["company/sync"]
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 600
    },
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

From what I've read, is the package is marked as a `silverstripe-module` it should put it at the root of the installation. I've also tried to set it via the `extra` parameter however it is still placed at vendor/company/sync. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is your custom "repositories" entry. By defining a "package" entry, you're telling composer the properties of the package and it won't look up the `composer.json` of your repository.

So either you fully define the "package" entry by also adding "type" and other fields, or just use a "vcs" entry (which will use your `composer.json` from your repository). Eg.

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "git@xxx:xxx/sync.git"
    }
]
```

In short: Use "vcs" for repositories that have their own `composer.json` and only use "package" if you rely on sources that don't have any composer metadata.